# How to Temporarily Stop Drawing After Rectangle Complete

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/2m4qvzpa/1/) and let me know how I can stop drawing mood (until next click on rectangle drawing button) and change the cursor to google maps regular cursor (the way it looks after clicking on [image] button) in `rectanglecomplete` event listener?

I already tried adding the `drawingManager.setMap(null);` into the listener but this is disabling whole drawing proccess.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var map;
var drawingManager;
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT,
        drawingModes: [
             google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE      ]
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function (r) {
   // drawingManager.setMap(null);
});

drawingManager.setMap(map);
});
```

Comment: After you draw your object, wouldn't you just click on the "hand cursor" again to switch the cursor or do you want it automatically to be switched after the drawing has stopped (switching from cross cursor to hand cursor)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DrawingManagerOptions):

> drawingMode   Type:  OverlayType The DrawingManager's drawing mode, which defines the type of overlay to be added on the map. Accepted values are MARKER, POLYGON, POLYLINE, RECTANGLE, CIRCLE, or null. A drawing mode of null means that the user can interact with the map as normal, and clicks do not draw anything.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function (r) {
   drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2m4qvzpa/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var map;
  var drawingManager;
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(r) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 420px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=drawing"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="marker-position"></div>
```